# WordPress is replacing double minus signs in Post Title, how to disable it?

Tags: posts, title

sometimes i have Post Titles that contains 2 minus signs side by side (--) but wordpress is always removing one of the minus sign. Looks like:

`My--Text`

into

`My-Text`

any idea how to disable it?

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I believe you can stop that by disabling the wptexturize function:

```
<?php
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_title', 'wptexturize');
?>
```

... for example. You can add that to you themes functions.php file.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize